# VB.NET - Problem Reading Serial Port - " Waiting for Activation" Status

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I am new to Async, Await ,Task etc .

I am sending a Ascii command string  to serial port and then  reading a 9 bytes returned as the measured value from the port .

If the command  ( voltage measurement command ) is sent and received by the instrument it returns  9 bytes .  This is the normal case .  This works fine if there are 9 bytes to be read .

However , if nothing is  returned because the command string did not transmit properly (most likely) and then the instrument does not return anything ,then instead of the 9 bytes expected nothing is read and Read.status is "Waiting for Activation"

Now if i send the command again after the failed read event , then the measured value is not read properly . I get 5 bytes read instead of  the expected 9 bytes  or sometimes nothing is read

I am  reading the port using

`Dim read = Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(readback, readback.Length - bytesLeft, bytesLeft)`

Multiple read attempts  does not solve the problem  . It seems  `Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync()` latches in a particular state if the required no of bytes are not read and this is preserved until it is reset somehow . .I do not know how to reset it .

How can I reset the state  of `Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync()` after a failed read event so that if i try to send the command again and  read the port again it will work normally ?

Here is the `GetLoadVoltage` function code that sends the command and then calls the `ReadAllBytes` function to read back the measured value from the serial port .

Any help or advice appreciated !

```
Async Function GetLoadVoltage(address As UInt16, channel As UInt16, cancelToken As Threading.CancellationToken) As Task(Of Double) Implements ILoadComms.GetLoadVoltage

Try
            'Variables and Set-Up
            Dim trys = 0

            Dim command1 As Byte() =
               System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("@" + 
               address.ToString("00") + "L" + channel.ToString("0") + "V?")


            Await TimeLimitedWrite(command1)

            Dim readback1 = Await ReadAllBytes(9, cancelToken)


            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

            Dim adrs As String = address.ToString("00")
            Dim pattern As String = adrs + ":\d{3}\.\d{1}"
            Dim input As String = 
            Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readback1).Replace(vbCr, "")

            Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, 
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

            If m.Success Then
                Return CDbl(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readback1, 
                3, 5))
            Else
                While m.Success = False
                    If trys < 5 Then
                        StarPrint("Corrupted string " + input, _logs)
                        StarPrint("GetLoadVoltage Retry " + trys.ToString, 
                        _logs)
                        trys = trys + 1
                        command1 =
                        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("@" + 
                        address.ToString("00") +"L" + channel.ToString("0") 
                        + "V?")
                        Await TimeLimitedWrite(command1)
                        readback1 = Await ReadAllBytes(9, cancelToken)
                        input = 
                      Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readback1).Replace(vbCr, 
                       "")
                        m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, 
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                    Else
                        Throw New CommsInvalidException("GetLoadVotage(): 
                        Format exception 1")
                    End If
                End While
                Return CDbl(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readback1, 
               3, 5))
            End If
        Catch cancelEx As OperationCanceledException
            Throw
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function '
```

***************This is the Read Function  ************

```
Protected Async Function ReadAllBytes(expectedBytes As Integer, cancelToken As Threading.CancellationToken) As Task(Of Byte())

Try
            Dim trys = 0
            Dim readback(expectedBytes - 1) As Byte
            Dim bytesLeft = expectedBytes

            readWatch.Reset()
            readWatch.Start()

            While bytesLeft <> 0
                Dim read = Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(readback, readback.Length - bytesLeft, bytesLeft)
                Await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(5000), read)

                While read.IsCompleted = False
                    If trys < 5 Then
                        _logs.PrintToDebug("Read all bytes RETRY : " + trys.ToString)
                        trys = trys + 1
                        read = Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(readback, readback.Length - bytesLeft, bytesLeft)
                        Await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(3000), read)

                    Else

                        ' If (Flagged.Contains(Port.PortName)) Then
                        'Flagged.Remove(Port.PortName)
                        'End If
                        'Return readback

                        Throw New CommsReadTimeoutException("ReadAsync Timed Out trying to read " +                 expectedBytes.ToString() + " Bytes")
                    End If
                End While

                bytesLeft = bytesLeft - read.Result
            End While

            If (Flagged.Contains(Port.PortName)) Then
                Flagged.Remove(Port.PortName)
            End If

            readWatch.Stop()
            Dim format As String = "{0,-10} {1,-5} {2, -10} {3, -10}"
            Dim rdBk As String = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readback).Replace(vbCr, "")
            Dim Milli As String = "Ms: " + readWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString ' Ms for milliseconds
            Dim PrtNme As String = Port.PortName
            Dim rd As String = "READ"
            _logs.PrintToDebug(String.Format(format, Milli, PrtNme, rd, rdBk))

            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            Return readback
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            _logs.PrintToDebug("ReadAsync Eror trying to read")
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("ReadAsync Error: " + ex.Message, ex)
        Catch ex As CommsReadTimeoutException
            _logs.PrintToDebug(ex.Message)


            Throw
        End Try
    End Function'
```

Comment: This is turning into a convoluted mess.  Focus on the real problem, anything you write should not just disappear.  Typically caused by a *very* common bug, nobody understands what the Handshake property does.  Handshake.None is almost never the correct choice.

Comment: Maybe the problem with this code is it is reading a fixed number of bytes . This is fine if everything works as expected . However this is not robust . If there is an error where the expected number of bytes is not received then it  will throw an exception . I want to make it more reliable with recovery via a Retry  if nothing is received back on a Read or if there is an unexpected byte character received or a wrong number of  bytes are received . It is part of a long running test process so it must be able to run for hours or days reliably .

Comment: If the Dim read = Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync() does not receive the expected number of bytes when the port is read , then it is not possible to  read the port after this event .  If nothing is received for example , then after this event no data is received  and the  read.status shows "Waiting for Activation" even though there should be data received . Bytes to Read is showing 0 .  The port  seems to latch up in a fault state if the expected number of bytes is not received and i do not know how to reset it . How to  reset it via software change  after this event ?

Comment: Hans . We are only receiving 9 bytes . So it should not be a handshaking issue . The problem we have is when nothing is received and  we tell it to read 9 bytes . Then after this event if we send the measure Command again to the instrument  and read it again we still get nothing received , and "Bytes to Read is showing 0 . It seems to be a latched condition . How to reset it ?

Comment: Solved:  If the Port.Bastream.ReadAsync() method does not receive the the number of bytes specified when it reads the port you need to call Port.DiscardInBuffer()  after the failed read then send the command string to the instrument /device connected to the serial port and read the serial port again. Then it works. Use as  Retry function in the case of a failed send/receive communication .  I came across very useful free port sniffer/monitor software available here http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/index.html. I hope this information helps others navigate this issue . E Hannan

Comment: Hmm, ReadAsync() only ever returns 9 bytes by accident.  You only get what's present in the receive buffer, typically 1 or 2 bytes if the code is efficient enough.  Artificially slowing it down with the debugger, single-stepping the code, is one way to slow it down and get 9.  Repeatedly calling it is required to get all of them.  Never use DiscardInBuffer(),  you don't know what you throw away.